# Laravel Custom Form Type

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel, we can do forms with this:

```
{{Form::radio(name, value, checked, options)}}
{{Form::checkbox(name, value, checked, options)}}
{{Form::select(name, list, selected, options)}}
{{Form::text(name, value, options)}}
{{Form::textarea(name, value, options)}}
```

But, how can we do for custom type of input? For example:

```
<input type='color' name='color' class='colorpicker' />
```

I have tried with this, but it doesn't work:

```
{{Form::text('color', null, array("type"=>"color"))}}
```

How can I achieve that with Laravel form?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To generate an input with type `color`, you need to use the `input` method:

```
{{ Form::input('color', 'car_color', null, array('class' => 'input-big')) }}
```

This is the declaration of the `input` method:

```
public function input($type, $name, $value = null, $options = array()) { ... }
```